# How to hide balloon tooltip on touch screen smartphones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, touchscreen, balloon-tip

I'm newbie to JavaScript. I used the search to find solution for my problem, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I am using [this](http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html) **jquery.balloon.js**, which transforms the default browser rendering of the tooltip to customized one (with adding some CSS to it – background, border, etc.).

This is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').balloon({ 
  position: "bottom",
  tipSize: "0"
 });
});
```

Everything works just fine: when I hover the mouse on a link with included `title` attribute, the tooltip shows up customized. When I hover out the mouse the tooltip hides.

**The problem comes when browsing on touch screen devices.**

There is no mouse for hovering, so I tap once on the link and the balloon tooltip shows up (the link does not activate, the link is activated only when I tap twice), but then the tooltip does not hide. I tap somewhere on the body, but the tooltip remains on the screen.

I know how to hide elements in JavaScript by clicking/tapping outside them (in the `html` or `body`) with `$('html').click(function() { //code });`, but here the problem is that the tooltip is not an element, but attribute...

**How to hide only the tooltip with tapping somewhere in the body?**

You can test this behavior on the **jquery.balloon.js** site [here](http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html) with any touch screen device to see that once activated by tapping the tooltip can't hide.

Comment: Instead of editing the solution into your question, add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the only answer, but I figured it out.

I have created a `class` with the following code:

```
$.balloon.defaults.classname = ".balloon";
$.balloon.defaults.css = null;
```

This way I created `.balloon` class which allowed me to customize the tooltip by myself. I used this code to hide the tooltip by hiding the `.balloon` (which hides the newly customized jQuery tooltip):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('body').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.balloon').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the hideBalloon function.